# How to use Intel Quick Sync Video to encode in VP9 using ffmpeg on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vp9

How do I use ffmpeg on Windows using Intel Quick Sync Video (qsv) to encode a video in VP9? The command that I am using now is:

`ffmpeg.exe -init_hw_device qsv=hw -filter_hw_device hw -i input.mkv -vf hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv -c:v vp9_qsv -b:v 10M -maxrate 10M -preset veryslow output.mkv`

Which produces the following error message:[image]

I must be quite close because if I use the same command but `hevc_qsv` instead of `vp9_qsv` it runs and gives the expected outcome. So what am I doing wrong?

I am using Windows 11 Pro and an 11th Gen Intel i5-1145G7 CPU, which is Tiger Lake and should support `vp9_qsv` according to [this support table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video#Hardware_decoding_and_encoding).

Comment: Are you trying to encode and decode VP9? Try encoding only: `ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -c:v vp9_qsv output.mkv`. In case it's not working, try updating Intel HD Graphics Driver.

Comment: @Rotem it is encoding only. Your suggested command is how I started but then it complains about needing to open a hardware device. I am fairly sure my command as posted is the right approach because it works for `h264_qsv` and for `hevc_qsv`, which are family members of `vp9_qsv` and have the same interface. Updating the GPU drivers is worth a shot. Just for the record, this is not Intel HD graphics, but Xe graphics.

Comment: My CPU doesn't support VP9 encoding, so I can't test it. The following command `ffmpeg.exe -y -i input.mkv -c:v h264_qsv output.mkv` is working. When I add `hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv` there is an error (without `-init_hw_device`). When adding `-b:v 10M -maxrate 10M`, FFmpeg halts... You may try the latest stable (static build) from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) and from [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases). I had a case when one worked and the other didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Intel's QSV VP9 encoder wrapper implementation in FFmpeg is only supported on Linux at the moment. See [this commit](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/33583803e107b6d532def0f9d949364b01b6ad5a) for more details, specifically because VP9 encoding is tied to the low-power mode(s) exposed by the [`iHD` driver's](https://github.com/intel/media-driver) VDENC interface(s).

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more research.

It's not enough to check that the CPU has Quick Sync.  First you have to get the model number of the CPU (like i5-3590, i7-3770), which is how most hardware and software and vendors identify an Intel CPU. You can use this to do a web search and get to the web page where the CPU is described, such as https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80815/intel-core-i54590-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz.html .  If it says yes to QSV then you need the internal code name, which nobody else uses but which is essential to finding out what the CPU can actually do: this will be something like Raptor Lake, Aldor Lake, Muddy Water, Howling Wolf, etc.  You can then go to this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video where you can look up what exactly each processor can actually do. The CPUs in my systems have hardware decode for a number of codecs, but only partial support for decoding VP8 and VP9, and only go up to H.264 for hardware encoding.  I don't think this is listed anywhere on the Intel web site or anywhere "official", but the Wikipedia list seems to be accurate. This explains why I can't use hardware acceleration for encoding H.265 or VP9.  It would help if the ffmpeg error message was more accurate or specific, but I don't know what information the QSV software returns when you try to make it do something.